# Possibly lost a file after trying to rename it

Tags: mv

I had just created a script called `myscript`, and did a `chmod +x myscript` so it would execute.
I tried to execute `myscript` and realized I forgot the `.sh` extension.

So issued the following command in my `bash` shell:

```
mv myscript *.sh
```

... and voila, the file was no longer.  I searched all over for it by name and got lists of all files modified in the past hour, but I couldn't find the file.  Where did it go?  Is any other damage needing recovery?

Comment: Do you have a directory whose name matches `*.sh`?

Comment: What does `ls -ld *.sh` print now? Please [edit] and add this information to the question.

Comment: Also, extensions are almost entirely irrelevant in the *nix world. Very, very few programs use them (gzip is the only example I can think of off the top of my head), and there is absolutely no need to call your scripts `foo.sh` unless you want to for your own reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have either at least one directory or exactly one file matching the pattern `*.sh` in the current directory.

1. If it is a directory you will find the file `myscript` in that directory otherwise unharmed. Example

   ```
   mkdir dir.sh
   mv myscript *.sh
   ```

   Here the `mv` command is expanded by the shell to be `mv myscript dir.sh` and the file is moved into that directory.
2. If it is a file you will find that the file has been *replaced* with `myscript`. Example

   ```
   touch file.sh
   mv myscript *.sh
   ```

   Here the `mv` command is expanded by the shell to be `mv myscript file.sh` and the file is renamed as `file.sh`, overwriting whatever previous contents it might have contained.
3. If there are files and directories matching `*.sh` in the current directory it depends on whether the last item in the set (ordered alphanumerically according to your locale) is a file or a directory. In all cases the shell will expand the wildcard, for example, to `mv myscript file1.sh file2.sh lastdir.sh` or perhaps `mv myscript dir.sh file.sh`.

   - If a directory is the last item, all items also matched by the shell will be moved into that directory.
   - If a file is the last item, then the `mv` command will fail with an error, as multiple items cannot be renamed to a single target. (Seeing as you didn't report an error from `mv` this situation did not arise.)
4. Finally if there is nothing matching the pattern `*.sh` in the current directory, the shell will have probably left the pattern alone and passed it to `mv` as a literal. In this situation the `mv` command will rename the file to the literal string `*.sh`, including an asterisk as the first character.

I would guess that it's most likely action #2 identifies what has happened and you will have lost the original contents of the file matching the pattern `*.sh`.

Comment: Thanks, yes it did overwrite the one matching .sh file.  Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: @TexasTim I'm pleased you've found your file, even if unfortunately at the expense of another. If you are curious to see how the shell expands wildcards, you can generally prefix a command with `echo` and view the result. For example `echo mv myfile *.sh`.